# Building iOS cordova app on cross-platform windows agent (TFS)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, tfs

I was wondering if it's possible to build an iOS app with the cordova framework on a cross-platform Windows Build Agent : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/README.md

I'm using the Cordova build task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cordova-tasks, but I can't seem to run this on Windows.

Which prerequistes do I need to install on my Windows agent, or is it mandatory to have an OSX installation?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: At this time it is not possible to debug ios cordova app from visual studio directly, so it's also not able to achieve this on windows build agent. You may have to make the build to run on OSX.

Comment: The build agent needs to run on an MacOS machine to create builds for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an OSX agent to build iOS app. A more detailed instruction for this task can be found here: [Build Apache Cordova apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/cordova-build) and you can refer to [Building iOS on OSX](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/cordova-build#building-ios-on-osx) section for details.

Comment: Damn... Was hoping I didn't have to buy a mac book specificly for building iOS apps :(. Thanks for your awnser though.